# products not showing in category on frontend Magento 2, but they are showing record count on category navigation

Tags: magento2, products, category-products

our items are no longer showing for each category page on the frontend.

I have checked lots of items on the admin:

Enabled = yes

Product in website = yes

Product in category = yes
Stock status in stock = yes
Visibility = catalog, search
Reset index, Reindex and flush cache = yes

Website = https://www.theemporiumdirect.co.uk/

(item blocks such as New items, related items, upsell items are showing).

Any advise would be much appreciated!

Rik

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If it was working yesterday then you should not try other solutions. Please try commands after clearing cache manually from var folder. I checked the url but site is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for us was:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

Answer (score 0):

There must be some customization in list.phtml or corresponding block that maybe removing the products from the rendered product collection.

The question is too broad for some specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am sure the site was working yesterday as expected. We have not changed anything the past 24 hours however I am aware that our server host has been experiencing some stability issues.